# VSTO Word add-in user.config lost every update

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

We have a C# VSTO Word Add-In that stores some info in the app.config

The problem seems to be that MS Word stores the file in a path that includes the word version number. When a SP is applied to Word the version changes and the user loses all of his setting. Not great.

A path might look like this:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\.vsto_vstolo_Path_q2taxlgdunqxqdv2wicxb0hasydgkndo\15.0.4535.1507\user.config

Does anyone have a good way to avoid this?

Comment: I just noticed the same exact thing with Outlook 2013.  I don't remember this occurring with Outlook 2010 with regard to minor patches changing the version number.

Comment: How can I reproduce this? I've had a client report this error. But don't experience a problem when I roll back Office and then upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

According to this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx
you'll need to write your own settings provider:

> User.config files are not supported for VSTO apps (in general, where the host application is native, like Outlook, Word or even IE). In these cases, you will need to write your own settings provider (which is quite easy to do, by the way, and there are good samples and docs in MSDN that describe how to do this) to be able to read/write user scoped settings.

I haven't tried it myself yet, so I can't comment on the 'easy' opinion.  It seems like all you'd need to do is find a way to override the version part and make it dependent on your addins version and not Office.  I'll see if I can dig up any examples how to do this

**Update:**
Turns out LocalFileSettingsProvider is the default, and I was hoping there would be some 'version-like' property so you could extend LocalFileSettingsProvider and simply override the property, but in the solution linked below, it looks like the developer is forced to write a bunch of xml serialization code himself, which would seem to defeat the purpose.  In any event, I haven't tested the blogger's code but it appears to be a very hard-won solution:

http://kikistidbits.blogspot.com/2010/10/save-your-settingssettings-to-known.html

Answer (score -1):

you can change this behavior by using vstolocal in registy, refer to below link for more detail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question. The solution seems to be to save our own settings file instead of using the app one. We're saving it as JSON in the app data folder. This seems to be the approach take by others as well.

Comment: Can you explain your answer? I don't think it relates to the question either.